# Typeahead formatting with images in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bloodhound

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: Bootstrap3_Problem_1]

Roughly how I want it to look like, displayed in row form, with the picture to the left and then the name to the right but without the scroll

[image: Bootstrap3_Problem_2]

The typeahead also breaks my input-form, it should reach all the way to the search button (and does if I disable the typeahead). Any ideas on how to fix this?

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="input-group typeahead">
        <input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" name="query" id="query" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" 
          spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type a hero">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
              </span> Search
            </button>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var all_heroes = [{
    name: "Axe",
    picture: "http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/axe_lg.png"
}, {
    name: "Anti-Mage",
    picture: "http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/antimage_lg.png"
}, {
    name: "Storm Spirit",
    picture: "http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/storm_spirit_lg.png"
}];

//$("#query").typeahead({ source:heroes});


var heroes = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: all_heroes
});
heroes.initialize();
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1,
}, {
    name: 'heroes',
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: heroes.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        empty: 'not found', //optional
        suggestion: function(el) {
            return '<img src="' + el.picture + '" />' + el.name
        }
    }
});
```